# How to correctly read a csv-file with single quotes?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datatable

Trying to read `.csv`-file, which rows look like these:

`gif,940ff2312-4325-8898dfs-9ce1ca56c5sfb,'[{"mid": "/m/083dsf", "description": "buff", "probability": 0.9663228988647461, "topic": 0.9663228988647461}]'`

I need to read these lines and put it into two lists: `gif`and `bif`. Every list must contain tuples of pair: first string (*'gif' in my example*), list of **dictionaries** (*third element in single quotes in my example*).

I can't find out how to correctly parse it, since `read_csv` doing it raising an error. Tried simple string approach, it works, but it's complicated to repair list of dictionaries and I think it's not good/not optimal. Tried JSON --- not working.

Here is my approach:

```py
gif = []
bif = []

with open('file.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        obj = line[:line.find(',')]
        arr = line[line.find('['):-2]
        json_acceptable_string = arr.replace("'", "\"")
        arr = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
        
        if obj == 'gif':
            gif.append((obj, arr))
        elif obj == 'bif':
            bif.append((obj, arr))
```

Any ideas how to solve it? Maybe there is some misunderstandings and good hacks in `pandas`?

**UPD:** Also I tried it this way:

```py
import csv

gif = []
bif = []

with open('file.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
    for line in csv_reader:
        for obj, Id, objArr in line: # here I'm trying to split it in 3 objects
            if obj == 'gif':
                gif.append((obj, arr))
            elif obj == 'bif':
                bif.append((obj, arr))
```

But it raises:

```py
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Comment: not sure about your objective. what you could do is  read the file like this `df=pd.read_csv("touch.csv",header=None,quotechar="'",names=['key','code','arr'])` and then you can build json like this `values=[json.dumps(each) for each in df['arr']]` . If you can show the output you are looking for then can be more specific.

Comment: If you are getting an error, print the offending line.

Comment: The ValueError is correct - you're attempting to iterate across the line 3 items at a time, while only 1 item (item) is available. You have to replace the second for-loop with: `obj, Id, objArr = *line` - however, as that relies on unpacking and the parsed line length being the same, it's unclear and should be avoided. You could do: `obj = line[0]`, `Id = line[1]`, and `objArr = line[1]` which is clearer but more verbose.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga on the input was just a list of three strings vals, as I mentioned in post:

Comment: I will also add that the ValueError occurs after the csv reader, which indicates that the line is being parsed properly by the module when using `quotechar`.

Comment: @jrd1 thanks a lot! But one more question: probably JSON way is better since it is easier to reconstruct my dictionaries (I need them)?

Comment: @taciturno: What do you mean by "JSON way"?

Comment: @jrd1 by using```json.loads(row[-1])``` --- it will be list of ```dict()``` isn't it?

Comment: @taciturno: Yep, that's correct. Although, it will be a list of size 1 in this case. The other columns can be accessed as normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231960/discussion-between-taciturno-and-jrd1).

Comment: @simpleApp, it's a good approach, it is needs to add ```json.loads()``` for each ```json.dumps()```, but I can't figure out why it's remains strings, not dictionaries in result...

Comment: let me add an answer, so it helps.

Comment: @taciturno - added my response for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `quotechar` [format parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) to correctly parse the single-quoted JSON string:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        # If you want to parse the json, you can do:
        # `json.loads(row[-1])` (requires the json module)
        # Kudos to @juanpa.arrivillaga for the suggestion!
```

This yields the following output given the sample data you provided, as desired:

```
['gif', 
 '940ff2312-4325-8898dfs-9ce1ca56c5sfb', 
 '[{"mid": "/m/083dsf", "description": "buff", "probability": 0.9663228988647461, "topic": 0.9663228988647461}]']
```

Comment: Good answer, for the sake of completeness, you an just show the op `json.loads(row[2])`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I used ```csv.reader``` also and was given an error. I'll update post with given error, check it please

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks! That's a good idea - edited.

Comment: @taciturno: What error did you obtain? I used the sample data you provided as well as some other generated data and they are parsed properly with this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In CSV file data is as

`gif,940ff2312-4325-8898dfs-9ce1ca56c5sfb,'[{"mid": "/m/083dsf", "description": "buff", "probability": 0.9663228988647461, "topic": 0.9663228988647461}]'`
to handle the array in single quote, pandas read_csv constructor has `"quotechar="'"`

read as dataframe:

```
df=pd.read_csv("touch.csv",header=None,quotechar="'",names=['key','code','arr'])
```

one way is dump as json:

```
import json
for each in df['arr']:
    my_json=json.dumps(each)
    print(my_json)
```

Another way could be read as a dictionary data structure, and ast module can be handy here. So read it as a string and convert it to the dictionary.

```
my_list_of_dictionary=[ast.literal_eval (each.replace("[","").replace("]","")) for each in df['arr'] ]
for each_dict in my_list_of_dictionary:
    print(f"Type:{type(each_dict)} value: {each_dict}")
```

output:
[image]